# How to fetch id from <div> tag using xpath if its has multiple classes with same classname

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

Please find the HTML :

```
<div id="086" data-activity-type="CompatCheck" class="Activity"></div>
```

Here only constant value is `data-activity-type="CompatCheck"` and classname  is same for all the other elements.

while trying to print id using `data-activity-type` i.e. *CompatCheck* using xpath

Expected output:

```
086
```

Problem 2 : Observed that the only unique value is id, how can we fetch in this case.

Please Find the HTML :

```
<div id="0007" data-activity-type="CompatCheck" class="Activity"></div>
                                
<div id="110007" data-activity-type="CompatCheck" class="Activity"</div>
```

While trying to use following code line :

```
findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-activity-type='CompatCheck']")).getAttribute("id");
```

I'm getting only first id i.e; 0007

but I need always the second  id="110007", can you please suggest to get the second id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the attribute `data-activity-type="CompatCheck"` is unique you can use it and you can use either of the following the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447)::

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[data-activity-type='CompatCheck']")).getAttribute("id"));
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-activity-type='CompatCheck']")).getAttribute("id"));
  ```

Console output:

```
086
```

Answer (score 1):

With XPath or CSS Selectors you can locate web element based on any constant attribute value. I.e. it can be based on constant class name value or id or any other attribute. In your case the constant attribute value is `data-activity-type="CompatCheck"`. So, you can locate this element by XPath or by CSS Selector and then extract the `id` attribute as following:
XPath

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-activity-type='CompatCheck']")).getAttribute("id");
```

CSS Selector

```java
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[data-activity-type='CompatCheck']")).getAttribute("id");
```

Comment: @undetected Selenium & Prophet the code mentioned from your side it worked, but i'm facing another issue on the same i'm getting always the first id but i needed only the second id , I've edited and mentioned in the problem statement 2 could you please look into it,thanks

Comment: You need to ask a new, separate question for that. initially asked question is already answered and resolved here

Comment: Hi @Prophet i have raised a new question kindly please look into it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75148673/how-to-fetch-second-id-from-div-tag-using-xpath-if-its-has-multiple-classes-wi

Comment: I see. Already answered there. Let me know if that worked or you still need some kind of fixes / clarifications there

Comment: yeah that worked but I'm still not getting relevant output , have raised a new case could you please look into it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75152993/how-to-fetch-id-from-div-tag-using-xpath-in-efficient-way