# How to fetch second id from <div> tag using xpath if its has multiple classes with same classname and multiple div tag

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

Observed that the only unique value is id, how can we fetch in this case.

Please Find the HTML :

```
<div id="0007" data-activity-type="CompatCheck" class="Activity"></div>
                                
<div id="110007" data-activity-type="CompatCheck" class="Activity"</div>
```

While trying to use following code line :

```
findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-activity-type='CompatCheck']")).getAttribute("id");
```

I'm getting only first id i.e; 0007

but I need always the second id="110007", can you please suggest to get the second id

Expected output : 110007

Comment: If possible please share a link to that page so we will be able to make some minimal check / debugging

Comment: Sorry That link has limited access, so even its shared wont be able to access it,have detailly specified html code in this case, could you please look into it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75152993/how-to-fetch-id-from-div-tag-using-xpath-in-efficient-way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you always need the second element id you can update your XPath accordingly.
This should work:

```java
findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@data-activity-type='CompatCheck'])[2]")).getAttribute("id");
```

Comment: Hi @Prophet thanks it really worked, I'm getting desired output but sometimes don't looks like I'm missing some where